# Working with column values in datatable (.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to loop through the values in a column in a datatable in an if statement like this:

If dt.columns("ModifiedDate") < Date.Now Then...

What is the sytanx for this?

EDIT: Getting data from a SQL query and needing to work with it and retain it.  I believe DataTableReader would be preferred here, unless DataReader can achieve the same thing. So I guess my question is now, which access method would be best for this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do inside the If block. Also, we lack context. How are you currently connecting to the database?

Comment: Yes, more context.  Columns are columns not data - you probably want to iterate rows looking at a specific item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dt is a DataTableReader you can do...

```
Do While dt.Read()
      If IsDate(dt("PatientID").ToString()) Then
         If CDate(dt("PatientID").ToString()) < Now Then 
             'do something
         End IF
       End IF
Loop
```

Greg

Comment: Thanks, dtr = dt.CreateDataReader

            Do While dtr.Read
                If dtr("ModifiedDate") < Date.Now Then
                    Console.WriteLine("YES")
                End If
            Loop

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the rows

```
for(int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    if(dt.Rows[row]["ModifiedDate"] < DateTime.Now)
    {
        enter you code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datatable is a DataGridView on a form, I use this code, however it can be modified to suit your needs:

```
    Dim Type As String = "STRING YOU ARE SEARCHING FOR"
    Dim RecordsFound As Integer = 0

'GET AMOUNT OF ROWS IN DATATABLE
    For index As Integer = 0 To Form1.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

'CHECK VALUE OF EACH ROW AND STORE IT IN "TYPECHECK"
        Dim TypeCheck = (Form1.DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(4).Value)

'COMPARE DATATABLE WITH VARIABLE STRING, IF THE SAME, INCREMENT "RECORDS FOUND"
        If TypeCheck = Type Then
            RecordsFound = RecordsFound + 1
        End If
    Next

'OUTPUT TO FORM TEXTBOX
    Form1.RecordsFound.Text = RecordsFound
```